# new Date().time or new Date.getTime() returning negative number?

Tags: actionscript-3, date

if I trace `new Date().toUTCString()` I get something like: Fri Aug 12 07:14:06 2011 UTC. perfect. If I trace `new Date().getTime()` I get some long negative number which is decreasing as I continue to trace it. This is totally unexpected. Obviously my system clock is OK. What gives?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`new Date().getTime()` returns time in milliseconds from January 1, 1970, universal time](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#getTime%28%29). It is positive number but I suppose you're using `int` to store it so Flash Player converts milliseconds to negative as far as it is more than `int.MAX_VALUE`. Use `Number` to store the value of `new Date().getTime()` and it will be positive.

Comment: This is a very good observation. It doesn't explain though why when I `trace(new Date().getTime());` I get a negative number, does it? Or is there some implicit conversion to `int` during the trace's call to `toString()`?

Answer (score 1):

What timezone are you in?

Are you by any chance in a time zone which is xxx seconds earlier than Greenwich?

Try setting the timezone to

timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("YOUR TIME ZONE HERE"));